# Access Last Mail Only (redhat)

Tags: rhel, email

I'm working on a redhat server with a lot of cron jobs. What I have been doing is `cat var/spool/mail/uname`. However, the size of it is constantly growing and causes me to lose previous console stuff from earlier.

Is there an alternative to the naive `cat` that will allow me to only print the most recent mail?

Comment: usually folks use a mail reader (e.g. `mutt`) to look at mails. another option would be to eliminate what I call cron spam so there are not a bazillion mails to read

Comment: ... or fix the cron jobs to do proper logging and to not spew thing onto standard output or standard error.

Comment: Is the mail folder I specified the same as "standard output"? This is my first time with Cron, I’m not the dba, and it appears to be happening automatically. Mutt looks like a good solution

Answer (score 2):

Try using mailx:  Type `mail` and then `$` to read your last mail message.